# URI of a file in LocalCacheFolder in a UWP app

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a media file which I am saving in the `LocalCacheFolder` (because I don't want it to be backed up). I want to play the file using the `MediaElement` by setting the `Source` to the URI of the file. The problem is I don't know what the URI would look like.

This is the code that saves the file:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder;

var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(id, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, video);
```

If I was saving to `LocalFolder` the URI would look something like this:

```
ms-appdata:///local/myfile
```

but what would it look like for `LocalCacheFolder`?

**UPDATE**

So, I've done some more testing and it looks like the URI should be

```
ms-appdata:///localcache/myfile
```

This works perfectly if I use `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` to access the file, but if I set this as the source of the `MediaElement` I get an invalid file path error.

Just to be sure there wasn't an issue with the files I changes my code to use
`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and `ms-appdata:///local/myfile` style URIs and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want play `StorageFile` in `MediaElement` you should use `SetSource` method:

```
var fileStream = await myStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);        
mediaElement.SetSource(fileStream, myStorageFile.ContentType);
```

Comment: The original problem still exists though :/